# Jquery accordion: populating text fields in dynamically created panels

Tags: jquery, html, tags, field, accordion

I would then like to populate the field of dynamically created accordion panels in a jquery accordion model. The field is to be populated with information from the main question field. I can create the dynamic panels with a jquery function, but I am having trouble in how to populate the panel field with the data from the main text field in my program (at the top

I can do the reverse, i.e. populate the main field with the panel field with the click of the 'edit' button.

Here is the output: https://jsfiddle.net/0fysejrh/1/

My code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  var counter = 3;
  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        });
    collapsible: true;

    function edit(){
    var text = $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
    var sql = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();
    $("#input").val(text);
    }
    $(":button").click(edit);

    $("#addAccordion").click( function() {
        var newDiv = '<div><h3>Question '+ counter +'</h3></div>';
        var content = '<div class = "new_panel"><label for="in" name="question">Edit Question:</label> <input type="text" name = "question" /><br><br>' +
        '<br><br> <input type = "button" value = "Edit" ></input></div>';
        $("#accordion").append(newDiv +content) ;
        $("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
        $(".new_panel").children("input[type=text]").val()==$("#input").val();

        counter++;
        $(":button").click(edit);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<form id="myform">
    <label>Enter Question:</label>
    <input id="input" type="text" name = "questions"/>
    <br><br>
    <input id = "submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type = "button" id ="addAccordion" value = "Add Question" ></input>
</form>
</center>

<div id = "accordion">
    <h3> Question 1 </h3>
    <div>
        <form>
            How many times a day do you take ventolin ?
            <br><br>

            <label for="in" name="question">Edit Question:</label>
            <input type="text" name = "question" />

            <br><br>
            <input type = "button" value = "Edit" ></input>

            </form>
    </div>
    <h3> Question 2 </h3>
    <div>
        <form>
            Have you ever been tested for an STI?
            <br><br>
            <label for="in" name="question1">Edit Question:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
            <br><br>
            <input type = "button" value = "Edit" ></input>
            </form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the following line of code does not work:

```
$(".new_panel").children("input[type=text]").val()==$("#input").val();
```

where ".new_panel" is the class name that I have made dynamically, and "#input" is the unique id of the main text field.

I tried using the class i.d. of the new panel, but this does not seem to work. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is save the value of the input in a variable and then input it as part of the `newDiv`

```
var inputVal = $("#input").val();
var newDiv = '<h3>Question '+ counter +'</h3>';
var content = '<div class = "new-panel"><label for="in" name="question">Edit Question:</label> <input type="text" name = "question" value="'+inputVal+'" /><br><br>'+ '<br><br> <input type = "button" value = "Edit" ></input></form></div>';
$("#accordion").append(newDiv +content) ;
$("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
counter++;
$(":button").click(edit);
```

you where also using == you have to remember that is a comparison not an asignment operator

https://jsfiddle.net/nyye5bmg/